# How should I shorten this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

In an email, I would like to write the following sentence:

> The weight of services given by
>   *Company B* is not less than the weight of services given by *Company
>   A*.

I want to shorten the sentence, but I'm not sure if this is correct:

> The weight of services given by
>   *Company B* is not less than *Company
>   A*.

What are my options for explaining this with just one sentence?

To make the context more clear: *Company A* and *Company B* are two partner firms in the same sector sharing the revenues according to specific conditions. They can merge or split in the near future. The aim of this sentence is to emphasize that the service quantity of *Company B* is larger than or (at worst) equal to the service quantity of *Company A*.

Comment: Are you talking about literal weight in this sentence? I can't tell without more context, but the phrase "weight of services" might be awkward-sounding English if you mean something like "breadth of services".

Comment: @michaelmichael: Please see my edit.

Comment: Same question.  It's not clear what you have in mind by the *weight* or the *quantity* of the company-provided services. And do you mean services *provided* by instead of *given* by? Is this about providing services to customers or measuring some quantity of assets (?) for a business merger or split?  Not clear to me what you mean to say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like Jimi Oke's shortest suggestion, but I will also add one further minor tweak:

> The weight of services given by Company B is **no** less than that of Company A.

"No less than" is a better idiom for expressing "at least equal to".

Answer (score 5):

Options for contraction:

> - The weight of services given by Company B is not less than *that of* Company A.
> - The weight of services given by Company B is not less than *that of those given by* Company A.
> - The weight of services given by Company B is not less than *the weight of those given by* Company A.

A couple suggestions that could do the job just as well, or better:

> - Company B offers just as many services as [does] Company A.
> - Company B offers just as substantial a range of services as [does] Company A.
> - The range of services offered by Company B is as broad/substantial as that of Company A.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal is OK, but to lessen the (remote) possibility of someone taking it to mean that "Company A weighs as much as the services," you could say:

> The weight of services given by Company B is not less than that of Company A.

I am guessing, but by not saying company B has MORE weight than A, I assume then that they are the same. In that case:

> The weight of services given by both companies is comparable.

Comment: It is perfectly grammatical. If you think it isn't please do explain why to the original poster.

Comment: So correct grammar, but possible misinterpretation of meaning: the opposite of what you wrote and exactly what I wrote.

Comment: That is a new definition of the word "grammar." Grammar is about structure and form, not meaning or intention.

Comment: You are still conflating intention with grammaticality. It is a ridiculous assertion that an utterance which failed to convey the *intended* meaning is ungrammatical. (missed your most recent comment)

Comment: And yet the first sentence is grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Strange phrase "weight of services" does 'weight' imply weakness (as in burden) or strength?

How about "Company A's services outweigh Company B's"?