# Which is correct: "not less than" or "no less than"?

Tags: idioms

Which is the correct idiom: "not less than" or "no less than"?

Example (edited):

> There were no less than fifty people at the meeting.
>
> There were not less than fifty people at the meeting.

Comment: Neither is grammatically (assuming we accept the modern usage of 'less' with count nouns in circumstances like this) or logically incorrect. However, I'd only expect to come across 'I found not less than five parcels at my doorstep.' in a maths problem. It's not idiomatic English. 'I found no less than five parcels at my doorstep.' means 'I found five – _five_ – parcels at my doorstep.' 'No less than' is an emphasiser rather than a quantifier here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - If you were to submit this as an answer rather than as a comment, I would upvote it.  :-)

Comment: @Erik I've got a good mind to join the club and beat you over the head with it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - There must be a technical term for the figure of speech you just used, but I'm feeling too browbeaten to identify it. (Bathetic, eh?)

Comment: A _Marxism_. (And hence unanalysable by sane linguists.) The reason a lot of valid stuff is confined to 'comments' is that the question is considered borderline off-topic, usually better suited for ELL rather than ELU. I wouldn't have gone as far as the downvoter here, though.

Comment: I changed the example to hopefully a better one. "No less than" has the meaning of "at least", but puts more emphasis on the finding.

Comment: For the down-voters; this is a genuine question of a non-native speaker. The very same question is asked more often on the net: [example 1](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=340875), [example 2](http://www.englishforums.com/English/NoLessThanNotLessThan/cjdng/post.htm) and [example 3](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14744/how-should-i-contract-this-sentence). I experience this down-voting and some of the comments as pretentious, offensive and not very welcoming. There are better ways to help a non-native speaker.

Comment: You might do better over at ELL, Gin. But your question as it now stands is subtly different, with 'fifty' being a rough figure (5 couldn't be in normal conversation) – and so, I'd say, belongs here. I'd say the first sentence is now ambiguous, either just being a paraphrase of the second (stating a fact – if not spot-on, at least giving an upper bound  – in an unmarked way) or retaining the pragmatic thrust (There were at least fifty – _fifty_ – people at the meeting!) I'd probably switch to 'There were no fewer than fifty people at the meeting.' for the bald statement of fact.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Upper bound? Surely it's a lower bound : _He was no less than 18 stones_ meaning _he weighed at least 18 stones_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for pointing me to the new [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) community. I was unaware of its existence.

Comment: @Frank Apologies, and thank you for the correction, Frank. Not being a female of the opposite sex, I was struggling thinking about the different possible meanings, the pragmatic rather than transparent factor, the difference moving from 5 to c50 elements makes; Gin's being downvoted ... and to think I taught maths :-0

Comment: If the question is really that simple and straight, then the answer is: Both are correct. If anymore details are needed, Google and then let us know what you found.

Comment: OK, the question was put on hold... but what about the related questions in the right column? Many have been answered with the same references. Be consequent.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the context. Both can be fine depending on what you want to say.

#### *No less than*

This is normally used to give emphasis. *There are no less than 5 different ways to do this.* It is by far the commonest form and the only one regularly used outside academic or technical literature (image generated by searching [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)  and [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) for *no less than*):

COCA:
[image]

BNC:
[image]

#### *Not less than*

This is indeed far less common but can also be used. I would use it in cases where I want to specify that the minimum required number is X. For example, *Use as many eggs as you like but not less than 5*. It is more common in technical literature than everyday speech though (image generated by searching [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) and [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) for *not less than*):

COCA:
[image]

BNC:
[image]

As you can see from the images above, *no less than* is far more common. However, *not less than* is also used and perfectly correct in some contexts, especially academic literature and on both sides of the Atlantic. Interestingly, it is also relatively common in the "misc" category in the British corpus, which includes religious and administrative literature.

Answer (score 3):

[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/no-less-than) has an entry for ***no less than***:

> used to show your surprise at a large number: There were no less than
>   a thousand people there buying tickets.

In the electronic version of the *Oxford Hachette Dictionary*, under the entry of "less" as an adverb, I read:

> no less than 85% *au moins 85%*

Answer (score -2):

Example 3 is a different construction altogether, so it is a red herring I will not be addressing.

In example 1 and 2, the variant with *not* strikes me personally as unidiomatic at best, and outright ungrammatical at worst. It is not something any native speaker I know would produce. It is worth noting that both examples, as well as this question here, were all asked by non-native speakers. Three out of three. So while it does seem to be a popular question among learners of the language, I do not feel it is a choice a native speaker ever feels presented with.

[COCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_of_Contemporary_American_English) and [BNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_National_Corpus) are not quite as radical as myself, but they do generally back me up:

```
                              COCA    BNC

there are no/not less than     8/1    5/0
there were no/not less than    7/1    8/0
there are no/not more than    21/4    8/3
there were no/not more than   23/1    5/1
```

The verdict seems to be rather clear, on both sides of the pond.

Comment: I am [Flemish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flanders) and I am not convinced of the existence of hard language borders. For example, the dialect in [Ostend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostend) has a lot of commonalities with English. Could it be that neighboring non-native speakers are reminding today's native speakers of expressions that have fallen into disuse on the isles?